# Detect access to camera and/or video from another apps in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, jitsi, jitsi-meet

We are developing an application using Electron that joins meetings through WebRTC.

We want to know if it is possible to detect when a call from another application (Skype, Facebook, etc.) was received in order to disable the camera and microphone of our application.

Is there an event that we can listen when a call comes in from another application? Or can we know when another application is also using the camera or microphone?

Regards

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?